# How to change the number of rows or panels of a multi panel after using facet.by in ggfunc, ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have the following code. Because variable TEST has three categories I am getting three panel plots (2x2 grid with last panel empty). I would like to have all three panels in a single row. Could please help me how can I do that? Appreciate your help. Thank you

```
plot <- df1 %>% filter(PKCYC=="Cycle") %>%
  mutate(DOSE=factor(DOSE)) %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY, TEST) %>%
  ggsummarystats(x = "COUNTRY", y = "value", 
  ggfunc = ggboxplot, add = c("jitter"), 
  color = "COUNTRY", palette = "npg",
  facet.by = c("TEST"), xlab=FALSE, ylab="value",   
  legend="none", 
  free.panels = TRUE,
  ggtheme = theme_bw())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have set `free.panels=TRUE`. Not sure what you intended with that (perhaps you want free *scales* per facet?). But if you want your panels in one row then simply drop it.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggpubr)

df <- mtcars
df$am <- factor(df$am)

ggsummarystats(
  df,
  x = "am", y = "mpg",
  ggfunc = ggboxplot, add = "jitter",
  color = "am", palette = "npg",
  facet.by = "cyl",
  labeller = "label_both",
  legend = "none",
  xlab = FALSE,
  ylab = "value"
)
```

[image]

And in case that you want free scales for the facets you could do so by setting `scales="free"`:

```r
ggsummarystats(
  df,
  x = "am", y = "mpg",
  ggfunc = ggboxplot, add = "jitter",
  color = "am", palette = "npg",
  facet.by = "cyl",
  labeller = "label_both",
  legend = "none",
  xlab = FALSE,
  ylab = "value",
  scales = "free"
)
```

[image]

Finally, for comparison and to reproduce your issue here is the **plot with `free.panels=TRUE`**:

```r
ggsummarystats(
  df,
  x = "am", y = "mpg",
  ggfunc = ggboxplot, add = "jitter",
  color = "am", palette = "npg",
  facet.by = "cyl",
  labeller = "label_both",
  legend = "none",
  xlab = FALSE,
  ylab = "value",
  free.panels = TRUE
)
```

[image]